# NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass error at omniauth gem testing

Tags: testing

i use omniauth-identity gem for authentication. first,i write tests. i got stucked at a test with omniauth-identity. my models and controllers are like this:

```
class Authentication
include Mongoid::Document
field :name, type: String
field :uid, type: String
field :provider, type: String

def self.from_omniauth(auth)
find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || create_with_omniauth(auth)
end

def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
create! do |user|
user.provider = auth["provider"]
user.uid = auth["uid"]
user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
end
end

def self.find_by_provider_and_uid(provider, uid)
where(provider: provider, uid: uid).first
end
end


class User < Authentication
include Mongoid::Document
include OmniAuth::Identity::Models::Mongoid

field :name, type: String
field :email, type: String
field :password_digest, type: String

validates_presence_of :name
validates_uniqueness_of :email
validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i
validates_length_of :password, minimum: 2, maximum: 16
end
```

these are my models. iuse a test code like this
    @user=Fabricate.build(:user) 
    @authentication = Authentication.create_with_omniauth(@auth)
    post :create,  @user

but this gives me error **"NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"** how can i solve this?

Comment: The error seems to indicate that certain classes which you use are not in the namespace. You need to make sure to require all the assets you need at the top of the file.